# SAP Crystal Report Pre-Requiste when installing windows set up project

Tags: crystal-reports, windows, prerequisites

We have a windows application with pre-requisite `SAP` crystal report for `.NET framework 4` . I selected:

> "Download prerequisites from the component vendor's website"

for the install location . In few machines, setup gets installed properly. But in some machines, it gives the following error message.

> Product: SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4
>   (32-bit) -- Setup detected an existing installation.  Setup must run
>   with UPGRADE=1 command.  Setup will now exit.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

it means you already have sap crystal report installed on your machine , try uninstalling it and then run the installation .